# How can I get DELETE queries from BigQuery job listing?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have an ingestion time partitioned table that doesn't have any row for a date range

```
#standardSQL
SELECT COUNT(*) AS rows_cnt,
       _PARTITIONTIME AS ptime
FROM my_dataset.my_table
WHERE _PARTITIONTIME BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-30'
GROUP BY ptime
-- result returned zero rows :o
```

I want to investigate: it's probable that the data in those partitions got wiped out using some deletion query.
I wrote a script to retrieve "suspicious" queries.Those having some kind of pattern

```
DELETE ...my_table .... 2017-01 ...
```

or simply DELETE jobs

here is the script

```
import re
import requests
import json
from pprint import pprint
from datetime import datetime
import subprocess
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-all_users', type=bool, default=True)
parser.add_argument('-projection', type=str, default='full')
parser.add_argument('-state_filter', type=str, default='done')
parser.add_argument('-access_token', type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()


def get_query_string(job):
    return job['configuration']['query']['query']

def log_job(job):
    with open('suspicious_jobs.txt', 'a+') as f:
        f.writelines(json.dumps(job))
        f.writelines('\n')

def is_suspicious_query(query_string):
    lower_query = query_string.lower()
    return re.search('delete.*my_table.*2017-01', lower_query) is not None

def is_delete_statement(job):
    return job['statistics']['query']['statementType'] == 'DELETE'

def is_copy_job(job):
    return job['configuration']['jobType'] == 'COPY'

def get_next_token():
    subprocess.check_call('gcloud auth login', shell=True)
    return subprocess.check_output('gcloud auth print-access-token', shell=True).decode('utf-8').strip()


all_users = args.all_users
projection = args.projection
state_filter = args.state_filter
query_url = """https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/my_project_id/jobs"""
access_token = get_next_token()

next_page_token = ''
page = 1
while next_page_token is not None:
    print('######## querying page ', page)
    url_parameters = {
    'allUsers': all_users,
    'pageToken': next_page_token,
    'projection': projection,
    'stateFilter': state_filter
    }
    headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(access_token)
    }
    r = requests.get(query_url, params=url_parameters, headers=headers)

    if r.status_code == 401:
        access_token = get_next_token()
        print(access_token)
        print(r.text)
        continue
    elif r.status_code != 200:
        print(r.text)
        print('###### last_page_token is ', next_page_token)
        break

    next_page_token = r.json().get('nextPageToken', None)
    jobs = r.json().get('jobs', [])
    for j in jobs:
        try:
            if is_copy_job(j):
                continue
            q = get_query_string(j)
            if is_suspicious_query(q) or is_delete_statement(j):
                log_job(j)

        except KeyError as e:
            pass

    page = page + 1
```

The `is_suspicious_query` function checks if the query matches the pattern `delete.*my_table.*2017-01`(case insensitive).

I couldn't find the job that did the deletion. Am I missing jobs in my while loop ? (I'm skipping whenever I have a KeyError exception)

Is it possible to delete table's partitions without the action being logged ?

Comment: all BQ API calls should be logged to the BQ audit log
have u checked here https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?resource=bigquery_resource ?

Comment: You should also check if the partitions were [overwritten](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-partitioned-table-data#append-overwrite) or a [partition expiration date](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-storage#use_the_expiration_settings_to_remove_unneeded_tables_and_partitions) was set

Comment: In order to get if the partitions were deleted because of an overwrite I used this advanced query filter `resource.type=("bigquery_project" OR "bigquery_dataset" OR "bigquery_resource")
protoPayload.metadata.jobChange.job.jobConfig.queryConfig.destinationTable:"my_table"` but there was no results. How should I search for partition expiration logs ?

Answer (score 1):

For this, I suggest using [Stackdriver advanced filters](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-filters#getting_started_with_advanced_filters) with the following filter:

```
resource.type="bigquery_resource"
protoPayload.serviceData.jobQueryRequest.query:"your_dataset.your_table"
protoPayload.serviceData.jobQueryResponse.job.jobConfiguration.query.statementType="DELETE"
```

With this, you'll got the DELETE operations made to the specified table.

UPDATE:

```
resource.type="bigquery_resource"
(protoPayload.methodName="jobservice.jobcompleted"
OR protoPayload.authorizationInfo.resource:"projects/<your-project>/datasets/<your-dataset>/tables/"
OR (protoPayload.serviceData.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobConfiguration.query.destinationTable.datasetId="<your-dataset>"
AND protoPayload.serviceData.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobConfiguration.query.destinationTable.tableId:"<your-table>"))
protoPayload.methodName!="tabledataservice.list"
"<yourdataset.yourtable>"
severity!="ERROR"
```

With this filter, you could find most of the operations made to a table, for instance a query that has a [WriteDisposition](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/auditlogs/rest/Shared.Types/WriteDisposition) with WRITE_TRUNCATE as a value, will truncate your table and write it from the beginning.
Notice that if you use `:` instead of `=` while using your filters, it works to search for partial strings.

Regarding your partition questions, as far as I know, when a partition is deleted it should be listed as DELETED within the logs. Moreover, you delete partitions [by using the command-line tool's](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-partitioned-tables#deleting_partitions_in_partitioned_tables) `bq rm` along with a [table decorator](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/table-decorators).

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this and I didn't get any result. I assume that partitions were not deleted because of a `DELETE` statement. Is it safe to say that the only other options to delete partitions in a date range are: load jobs (that overwrite partitions) and partition expiration. For load jobs I think I found a way to serach for the associated logs (cf my comment in the question). Is it the right filter to use ? how should I check for expirated partitions ? is there any other way to delete partitions ?